# delete entire row if any cell is empty

Tags: google-apps-script

Just like the title says. I found a solution if one column is blank, but not if any are blank.

I crafted this with the help of another post, though I don't have a clue re: google scripts.

```
function onEdit(e) {


 //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)); 
  //{"source":{},"range":{"rowStart":1,"rowEnd":1,"columnEnd":1,"columnStart":1},"value":"1","user":{"email":"","nickname":""},"authMode":{}}
  try {
    var ss = e.source; // Just pull the spreadsheet object from the one already being passed to onEdit
    var s = ss.getActiveSheet();

    // Conditions are by sheet and a single cell in a certain column
    if (s.getName() == 'Sheet1' &&  // change to your own 
        e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.columnEnd == 99 &&  // only look at edits happening in col C which is 3
        e.range.rowStart == e.range.rowEnd ) {  // only look at single row edits which will equal a single cell
      checkCellValue(e); 
    }
  } catch (error) { Logger.log(error); }
};

function checkCellValue(e) {
  if ( !e.value || e.value == 0) {  // Delete if value is zero or empty
    e.source.getActiveSheet().deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  }
}
```

problem is, I have no idea how to actually "use" it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Demo](http://youtu.be/wBnN0mzbsZQ) of the setup.

`e.range.columnStart` and `e.range.columnEnd` need to be equal to each other in this case

Answer (score 0):

In the spreadsheet that you'd like to use this in, click on Script Editor in the Tools menu. Select Blank Project in the dialog that comes up, and then replace the code in the window with the code you've posted above. Save and name your project, then click Current Project's Triggers in the Resources menu. Click the link to add a new trigger. You'll see a series of drop down boxes, select the function (onEdit()), From Spreadsheet (the event source), and "On Edit" (the event). You have the option to set failure notifications. Click save to save the trigger. You'll be prompted to provide authorization, once you do, the script should run as expected.

Comment: thanks, but I don't see any change. there's no drop-down to execute the script, and if I understand onEdit correctly, it's supposed to just happen automatically when I edit the document, correct?

Comment: That's what I would expect. I'll have to play with it a little.